# PLEASE assist me.. RE: *FORM FIELDS* I want to Hide() my "type=text box" until the Other option is chosen in the dropdown option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hide, show

````
**HTML**   
```<fieldset> 

        <legend>Basic Info</legend>

        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="user-name">

        <label for="mail">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" id="mail" name="user-email">

       <label for="title">Job Role</label>
        <select id="title" name="user-title">
          <option value="full-stack js developer">Full Stack JavaScript Developer</option>
          <option value="front-end developer">Front End Developer</option>
          <option value="back-end developer">Back End Developer</option>
          <option value="designer">Designer</option>          
          <option value="student">Student</option>
          <option value="other">Other</option>
      </select> 

      <input type="text" id="other-title" placeholder="Your Job Role"> 

    </fieldset>```
````

I AM ATTEMPTING TO:
DONE //Prevent any JQuery code from running before the document is finished loading 
DONE //focus 1st field by default

THIS IS MY ISSUE:
 //Hide text box until "other" is chosen from the Job Role//

````
**JS**
```$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form:first *:input[type!=hidden]:first').focus();
    $("Other").change(function(){
        if($(this).val() == "Other")
    {
        $("#other-title").show();
    }
    else
    {
        $("#other-title").hide();
    }
        });
                  $("#other-title").hide();
}); ```
````

Comment: A title really means *A title*. Should be short and concise. Can you try to edit your question to add more details about your issue?

Comment: Hey, @TaMarah first check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask then post questions. Secondly, you have to be very clear about what issue you are facing. Please format your question and be specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two main issues with your original code:

1- Using a wrong selector for the `onchange` event, replace `"Other"` by `"#title"`

2- You were checking if the value is equal to `"Other"` instead of the `"other"` you have in your HTML. Be careful, string comparison is case-sensitive!

Below is a working snippet after applying these two changes:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('form:first *:input[type!=hidden]:first').focus();
    $("#title").change(function(){
      if($(this).val() == "other") {
        $("#other-title").show();
      }
      else {
        $("#other-title").hide();
      }
    });
  $("#other-title").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset> 

        <legend>Basic Info</legend>

        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="user-name">

        <label for="mail">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" id="mail" name="user-email">

       <label for="title">Job Role</label>
        <select id="title" name="user-title">
          <option value="full-stack js developer">Full Stack JavaScript Developer</option>
          <option value="front-end developer">Front End Developer</option>
          <option value="back-end developer">Back End Developer</option>
          <option value="designer">Designer</option>          
          <option value="student">Student</option>
          <option value="other">Other</option>
      </select> 

      <input type="text" id="other-title" placeholder="Your Job Role"> 

    </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you've used value in a jquery selector.

```
$("Other").change(function(){
     if($(this).val() == "Other")
```

replace this line with below lines

```
$("#title").change(function(){
      if($(this).children('option:selected').val() == "other")
```

// You'll get selected value in dropdown by using below code.

```
$('#ELEMENT').children('option:selected').val()
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much.. This is what I found that worked , Replacing as you advised and adding the hide() method.  Code below

Answer (score 0):

By reviewing your question what I found was that the value specified in the select box for the "other" option is in lower case and the value you are comparing in the jquery on change code is in the sentence case.

And also the element identifier is not wrongly specified. You need to change it to "title"

```
<option value="Other">Other</option>

$("#title").change(function(){
   if($(this).val() == "Other")
   {
       $("#other-title").show();
   }
   else
   {
       $("#other-title").hide();
   }
 });
```

I hope that helps you.

Comment: If you find my answer useful please upvote my answer to help other community users.

Answer (score -1):

**THIS IS WHAT WORKED** Thank you EVERYONE :-) Anis R. On Point thats what helped

````
    $('#title').change(function(){
    if($('#title').val() == "other")
{
    $('#other-title').show();
}
else
{
    $('#other-title').hide();
}
    });
              $('#other-title').hide();
});```
````